# return an array from a recursive function

Tags: php, recursion, return

I think I need some explanations about the recursivity... I looked at some same issues over forums but it didn't help me a lot.

Here is my function :

```
public function tas ($nb_gift, array $winners)
{
    if ( !empty( $nb_gift ) ){
        $id_winner = rand( 10, 15 );
        if ( !$this->_in_array_r($id_winner, $winners) ){
            $existing_user = $this->getWinner( $id_winner );    
        }
        if( !empty( $existing_user ) && $nb_gift > 0 ){
            $winners[] = array( $existing_user, 'iphone5');
            $this->tas($nb_gift - 1, $winners);
        }
        else {
            if($nb_gift > 0)
            {
                $this->tas($nb_gift, $winners);
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        //print_r($winners);
        return $winners;
    }
}
```

At the end I have an array composed of the winners. Even if the print_r works, the return doesn't give me back my array.
Does the function need some optimisation ?

Answer (score 0):

You are never returning anything from the first `if` branch. If you call `tas()` initially and it goes into the first `if` branch, it never `return`s, hence the caller is never getting anything back.

Recursion is nothing special, really. You call a function, you get a result:

```
$winners = tas();
```

Simple. Internally that functions may call other functions:

```
function tas() {
    return foo();
}
```

There's no restriction that `tas` can't call itself, but it's still bound by the same rules of returned data:

```
function tas() {
    if (...) {
        foo(); // <-- doesn't return anything
    } else {
        return foo();
    }
}
```

Just substitute `foo()` in the above example by `tas()` for the same concept, but including recursion.